# How to get JObject's root name

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I cannot believe this is such difficult, but found no simple solution!

I have a JObject representing a JSON like

```
"MyData1": {
  "Data": "foo"
}
```

I need the root item's name (=Key) in the JObject, but don't like to iterate like it's proposed in other answers like this:

```
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
foreach (var tmp in jsonObject) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(tmp.Key);
}
```

This foreach construct gives me a KeyValuePair, which has the Key property.
How can I get this just for the very first item in my JObject?

(The only workaround I found is using a System.Xml.Linq.XDocument instead of JObject - this provides a Root.Name property.)

Comment: Break after first iteration

Comment: Yes, I considered this also - but there must a more elegant solution!?

Comment: ((JProperty)jsonObject[0]).Name

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Comment: can I add this as answer? @Nick

Comment: Yes, of course - I would just make it a bit safer like:
rootName = jsonObject.Count > 0 ? (jsonObject[0] as JProperty)?.Name : null;

Comment: Could you please share with us the `jsonString` as well?

Comment: @PeterCsala I added an example.

Comment: As an alternative you can perform the following check `jsonObject.First.Type == JTokenType.Property`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code to get the first key, please make sure your object is not null and has at least one item

```
((JProperty)jsonObject[0]).Name
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, but ((JProperty) jsonObject.First).Name did